# Select first row from group each by with count using Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

I've got over 500million rows stored in BigQuery which basically represent the exact position of a device at a certain time (irregular).

**I'm trying to find a fast and efficient way to determine the first and the last seen position of the device**.

So far, I have it working with a join but it's taking over 10 mins to complete (unless I just a limit in the query). I also tried with a dense_rank query but I can't sort the count out (and I don't fully understand it tbh).

I have a client_id, device_id (which is fixed and represents the location within the building) and a timestamp.

First I did a group by client_id and device_id to validate what I should expect. Then I tried joining the table using the min and max timestamp:

```
SELECT count(FirstSet.device_id), FirstSet.device_id
FROM
(
  SELECT client_id, device_id, created_at
  FROM [mytable.visitsv3]
  WHERE secret = 'xxx'
  GROUP each BY client_id, device_id, created_at
  ORDER BY client_id, created_at asc
  LIMIT 1000
) as FirstSet
inner join
(
  SELECT client_id, device_id, min(created_at)
  FROM [mytable.visitsv3]
  WHERE secret = 'xxx'
  GROUP each BY client_id, device_id, created_at
  LIMIT 1000
) SecondSet
on FirstSet.device_id = SecondSet.device_id
GROUP BY FirstSet.device_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC
limit 25
```

I'm new to this world so would appreciate some advice. As I said, it's more about performance as we need to run the queries live.

There's loads of tutorials about the same concept - I'm just hoping someone can help optimise things.

--- EDIT ---

Output format should look like so:

```
|count|device_id|
-----------------
|10000|      123|
| 9000|      345|
|  800|      234|
```

--- IN CONTEXT ---

We're trying to achieve a number of things with our dataset (not in a single query of course). Including:

- Create a heatmap of the most popular entry and exit points.

Initially this just needs to be a totals but long-term, we've got to understand which entry / exit points are busy at certain times of the day. And then use the correlation functions for some predictive analysis.

- Create paths of the clients as the move through the buildings.

Once we have the entry points, we need to map the paths the clients take. Again, we need to predict behaviour per day / hour etc.

**Initially, we just need the most popular entry / exit points. For this reason, we grouped the clients together and did a count of the devices they appeared on.**

The data looks like this:

```
client_id,device_id,created_at,start,end,duration,lat,lng
F047CA72E,0013BA30,2015-06-22 10:00:32 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:31 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:32 UTC,1,XX,YY
F40D8632F,00A30E00,2015-06-22 10:00:29 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:26 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:26 UTC,0,XX,YY
B808AA3E0,00138B20,2015-06-22 10:00:27 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:25 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:25 UTC,0,XX,YY
A0E532E96,00A33600,2015-06-22 10:00:34 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:24 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:25 UTC,1,XX,YY
D4F6F8D50,00149150,2015-06-22 10:00:34 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:22 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:22 UTC,0,XX,YY
70124EB7E,00A350A0,2015-06-22 10:00:33 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:14 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:14 UTC,0,XX,YY
200AF2A9E,00149090,2015-06-22 10:00:33 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:13 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:12 UTC,0,XX,YY
20AE4884A,0013EFC0,2015-06-22 10:00:30 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:13 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:13 UTC,0,XX,YY
CCD9BB01C,0013EFC0,2015-06-22 10:00:30 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:12 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:06 UTC,0,XX,YY
8CCE1F24E,0004165E,2015-06-22 10:00:12 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:12 UTC,2015-06-22 09:30:12 UTC,0,XX,YY
```

The count of the clients per device is in someways irrelevant as it will be normalised for the heatmap regardless. We just need them ranked so we can see most popular AND least popular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rephrase how I understand the setup:
- Devices are installed at fixed locations throughout the buildings
- Clients (people) move through the building at when they pass nearby the device, this event is recorded
- The time when client with client_id passes device with device_id is recorded in timestamp created_at

Therefore, the very first created_at timestamp for given client is when she entered the building, and the corresponding device_id will be an entry point. To find it, we can use

```
select 
  client_id, 
  first_value(device_id) 
     over(partition by client_id order by created_at asc) 
  as entry_device_id
```

In order to find 10 most popular entries, we can use TOP with COUNT(*), i.e.

```
select top(entry_device_id, 10), count(*)
```

Putting it all together:

```
select top(entry_device_id, 10), count(*) from (
  select 
    client_id, 
    first_value(device_id) 
       over(partition by client_id order by created_at asc) 
    as entry_device_id
  from [mytable.visitsv3]
)
```

Same things with exit points, but this time we will use last_value window function:

```
select top(exit_device_id, 10), count(*) from (
  select 
    client_id, 
    last_value(device_id) 
       over(partition by client_id order by created_at asc) 
    as exit_device_id
  from [mytable.visitsv3]
)
```

Comment: V. tidy query but gives wrong output. I need the aps grouped with a count desc. Have updated q. S

Comment: Can you clarify it a bit more - original question asked for first and last seen positions of the device, but the edited version asks for count. Is it count in the first position or in last position or something else ?

Comment: Apologies Mosha, I should have been clearer. (I suspect there will be two queries required.) I am trying to find the 'entry' and 'exit' points for the location based on the first and last time they were seen. Each building will have a number different possibilities which can change. Imagine walking in to a hospital, walking through and leaving at the other end. We'll pick up the device at multiple points but always have a start and end. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - the 'entry' and 'exit' make sense - I still trying to understand what does the count should count. Example with input data would help too :)

Comment: Let me put something together over the weekend. In brief, the count was to find the most popular points. That's why we'd grouped by device. Ideally, we'd know these per min, hour, day, week month. Although the total is what we're aiming for to start.

Comment: Have added some context and data to the question. Thank you once more for your help with this :)

Comment: Fantastic! Not only has that solved the problem, it's taught me many things. Query complete in 3.6s :) Happy days, thank you Mosha, we really appreciate the help.